# Rails Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip localization

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, tooltip

I am using Twitter-Bootstrap Tooltips and I want to know if there is a way or best practice of localize them? e.g.: in config/locales

My setup is:

Gemfile

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '~> 2.1.3'
```

bootstrap.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#plugin_description').tooltip({'trigger':'hover', 'title': 'ToolTip Text'})
```

Tooltips work fine, but is there a way to load the strings from config/locales? 
That would really be awesome :)

Update:
I want to use the tooltip with input fields in a form. Right now I have it like this:

```
= f.input :name
```

and call it with:

```
$('#application_name').tooltip({
    'placement':'top',
    'trigger':'hover', 
    'title': 'has to be unique and between 4 an 20 signs'})
```

but I couldn't find a way to localize the title attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip can take text from a link's title attribute, so internationalize your text there :

```
<%= link_to 'hover over me', '#', :id => 'plugin_description', :title => t(:tooltip_title) %>
```

#### UPDATE

You just supply the tooltip text with the `data-title` attribute.

In your JS:

```
$('.form-tooltip').tooltip({
  'placement':'top',
  'trigger':'hover'
});
```

Note that there is no `title` argument.

In your view :

```
= text_field_tag :name, '', :class => 'form-tooltip', :data => {:title => t(:'your.translation.key')}
```

It looks like you're using formatastic or simple_form so you'll need to adapt your view accordingly to generate the `data-title` attribute.

Comment: I updated my question, because i don't use it on links I want to use it with forms

Comment: No, I'm sorry. The tooltips wont load.

Comment: Have you reproduced the exact code that I posted? That has worked for me. Very hard to help without any further information!

Comment: Yes, i also did it while using simpleform. On the weekend I got more time to dig deeper. I will keep you informed :)